# contact 7 form won't send email

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to implement a contact form into my wordpress site I just deployed and I have sent hours trying to figure out why it isn't working. I have set up the
`Gmail SMTP plugin` and it says I am connected to smtp but I everytime I test out the form I get this error: `There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.`

my form keep giving me this error: 
[image]

these are my email settings on contact form 7:
[image]

any help would be appreciated! Please let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Personally I can't stand Contact Form 7.  I strongly prefer Gravity Forms.  HOWEVER, with that being said, I suspect your problem has to do with your *from* - is that the GMAIL account that you are using with SMTP?  What happens when you simplify this - remove the Additional Headers, and make the "From" simply your e-mail address?  If it sends successfully, then you can start adding things such as the reply-to, try again.  Modify the from, try again.  Figure out WHICH setting is breaking it, then you can tackle WHY that setting is breaking it.

Comment: Reading this could help you: [How to Send Email in WordPress using the Gmail SMTP Server](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-send-email-in-wordpress-using-the-gmail-smtp-server/). @cale_b The main reason using contact form 7 instead off Gravity Forms plugin, is that is a free plugin :)